# AWS Python SDK(boto3) has the error "Inexact: None" when access dynamoDB with decimal

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'm developing Lambda function (Python 2.7) which access to DynamoDB table.

The table has PK named datetime as string, and it also has columns named text as string type and num as number type.

datetime | text | num

20170101 | abcd | 1.1

20170201 | abcd | 1.5

20170301 | xyzz | 1.6

20170401 | abcd | 1.8

And I also set Global Secondary Index.
Partition Key is "text", and Sort Key is "num".
Because I want to get records whose "text" = "abcd and num between 1.3 and 1.9.

-> Get #2 and #4.

So, I develop the code.

```
TBL.query(
    IndexName='text-num-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('text').eq("abcd") & Key('num').between(1.3, 1.9)
)
```

However, my code has a error

**TypeError: Float types are not supported. Use Decimal types instead.**

So, I fixed the code to

```
TBL.query(
    IndexName='text-num-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('text').eq("abcd") & Key('num').between(decimal.Decimal(1.3), decimal.Decimal(1.9))
)
```

But there are another error

**Inexact: None**

Does the message mean "Loss of significant digits"??

Please give me how to solve the issue....

Comment: Checkout this issue https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/665

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply..

```
Key('num').between(Decimal(str(1.3)), Decimal(str(1.9)))
    )["Items"]
```

It's worked!! Thanks!!